# get value from mongoDB using php

Tags: php, mongodb

How to get the street value using 'php'?

```
{

    _id : "001",

    name : "fakename",

    address : {

                street : "12 Street",

                city : "Cosmos",

               }
}
```

Query :

```
$collection = database_name->collection_name;

$cursor = $collection->find ( array('name' => 'fakename' ), array( 'address.street' ) );

   foreach ( $cursor as $doc ) {

         echo $doc[ 'address.street' ];
   }
```

**Result :**

```
$doc[ 'address.street' ]
```

value does not get printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = (new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017"))->database_name;
$collection = $db->collection_name;
$cursor = $collection->find ( array('name' => 'fakename' ), array( 'address.street' ) );
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    echo $doc['address']['street'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses multidimensional arrays:

```
$doc['address']['street']
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it uses multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @YSuraj If this has answered your question, don't forget to mark the answer as correct so your question is resolved.